# JavaFX, order of commands (seemingly) ignored

Tags: java, javafx, label, sequence

I'm programing in JavaFX under java1.7, and everything works with my code except this part. The problem is, only the end result gets written out. While the program runs, I want it to display the "Ping test is running" text in the Label. But it won't do that, but instead waits a couple of seconds (till the ping finishes), than it writes out the result of the ping. Which looks bad, cause for 3-4 secs nothing happens and the user can think that it froze or something... hence the message I want to write out.
So, can someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? Thank you for your time.
PS: yes it needs to wait a few secs, in the `PingIp(...)`, so i can read the needed info correctly, otherwise I'm getting the null pointer error.

```
@FXML
private Label Ping;

@FXML
    private void Button(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        String text;
        Ping.setWrapText(true);
        Ping.setText("Ping test is running");
        text = PingIp.PingWifiAddr(GetIp.retIpWifi()).toString();
        text = text.substring(1, (text.length()-1));
        TeltonikaPing.setWrapText(true);
        TeltonikaPing.setText(text);
    }
```

below is the edited part

```
@FXML
    private void ciscoButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        CiscoPing.setWrapText(true);
        Task<Void> task1 = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override public Void call() throws IOException {
        String text1;
        text1 = "Ping teszt folyamatban";
        Ping.setWrapText(true);
                Ping.setText(text1);
                return null;

    }
};
new Thread(task1).start();

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override public Void call() throws IOException {
                String text2 = PingIp.PingEtherAddr(GetIp.retIpEther()).toString();
                text2 = text2.substring(1, (text2.length() - 1));
                Ping.setWrapText(true);
                Ping.setText(text2);
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
```

Above is the edited one, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you're doing all of the work on the JavaFX Application Thread. When you set some attribute, like the label's text, on the JavaFX Application Thread the results don't immediately get displayed. Instead, it waits until your code is finished running, at which point the framework takes over again and can display your changes.

In order to get around this, you need to execute long running code on a separate thread, to avoid blocking the redrawing of the GUI. Take a look at [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm) for details on how to implement that.

Comment: With this info, you did more than answer this question. You also made my GUI a LOT better :) Thank you for your time and the link.

Comment: @SzabóBalázs Glad to hear it. Hope your program goes well :)

Comment: It will take some time for me to understand, exactly how to implement this in my code, cause i'm fairly new to Java... but I'm confident that it will work in time :D

Comment: Hi ^^ I did it, it runs, but it still won't display "Pinging" while it works :S   Any ideas?

Comment: @SzabóBalázs try using `new Thread(task).start()` instead. `run()`, I believe, actually executes on you current thread rather than starting on the new one.

Comment: You were right about it, but the prvious part still won't aply before the thread. However if i modify it (like i edited again)
Than the first thread runs, but the second won't change anything. How can i tell the computer to run the second thread after the first?

Comment: @SzabóBalázs Unless I'm missing something, I don't think your first thread needs to be run as its own thread. If you move that functionality into the body of the method then it will complete in the order you want.

Comment: I did it, and than the 2nd thread (which is the only thread now) has no effect on the outcome.

Comment: @SzabóBalázs I feel like this is getting beyond the scope of the original problem. I think you'd be more likely to get a good answer quickly if you create a new question with the current problems you're facing. Then other people, who will be more familiar with multi-threading than me, will be able to help you.

Comment: Agreed :)
But thank you for all your help none the less.